# How to set variable if column is empty?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I have a variable, which I want to set as 0 only when the exact column in a table is empty. I've tried

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('ProductivityData.db')
c = conn.cursor()
if c.execute("SELECT LENGTH(xp_all) FROM graph") == -1:
    xp = 0
else:
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM graph")
    xp = c.fetchone()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

> (**graph** is a table, **xp_all** is a column in this table)

For sure it doesn't make sense and doesn't work. Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
if xp_all is empty:
    xp = 0
else:
    xp = the last item from xp_all
```

how can I do it? Maybe I could add 0 as a first item in xp_all, but how?

Comment: What do you mean by *column is empty*?

Comment: I'm not sure how should I call it, but I meant the thing that's inside a table, which can be text, blob etc... maybe it is called row? By empty, I meant that there is nothing inside, I haven't inserted anything

Comment: If you can't explain in words then clarify by posting sample data in a tabular format.

Comment: [this is how it looks like in code](https://imgur.com/a/Ytcr109) and [in some database tool](https://imgur.com/a/yoP9Y2k)

Answer (score 1):

"Empty" values in database columns are `NULL`s.

You can update these values like this

```sql
UPDATE graph SET xp_all = 0 WHERE xp_all IS NULL;
```

But it would be better to set a default for the column when the table is created

```sql
CREATE TABLE graph (..., xp_all INTEGER DEFAULT 0, ...);
```

or it you can specify that the column will not accept `NULL` values, in which case not provising a value will result in an `IntegrityError`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE graph (..., xp_all INTEGER NOT NULL, ...);
```

In some databases you could `ALTER` the `age` column on an existing table to take a default value.  This doesn't work for sqlite, you would need to create a new table with the correct settings, migrate the old table's data to the new table and then `DROP` the old table and rename the new table with the old table's name